# Is it possible to connect to more than a single bootnode?

Tags: networking

Right now I have one cloud instance running a node, and 2 local instances on the same computer. On my local instances, in the bootnodes flag I pass the address to my cloud instance. Initially I was expecting that this would result in `(2 peers)` showing up on each of my local instances, but only my cloud instance shows `(2 peers)`, the local instances show `(1 peer)`, which is the cloud instance.

Now my initial mental model was that this cloud instance would just be used as a means to sync up or discover other nodes in the network, and the nodes would then decide amongst themselves how to send communication to the fastest/nearest node, rather than the bootnode. Resulting in `(2 peers)` showing for each node (local or remote).

What I am asking is a networking question, does it happen that my local nodes could be communicating between themselves without going through the remote instance? Say `local A` produced a block, will that information be relayed directly to `local B` or through `remote` and then to `local B`?

Also, is it possible to use the bootnode as just a discovery point for other nodes? If not, is it possible to specify multiple bootnodes (if yes how)?

Comment: may I ask how you set up your cloud machine? I'm trying to do the same, but for some reason I can't get my local nodes to connect to the cloud node.

Comment: @edmassarani I suggest you ask a question on this forum and provide enough details to your problems to make it a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer the question as stated: yes, you can connect to multiple bootnodes.

Libp2p is meant to discover nodes from its connected nodes by using a [Kademlia](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/7a1147877a52c7150190acdef35676cdac370299/protocols/kad/src/lib.rs#L23) implementation of a Distributed Hash Table (DHT).

Oftentimes, in my experience, nodes on the same machine often discover each other without bootnodes through the use of [MDNS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762), which libp2p also implements. This is, for example, why you can run two nodes on a `--local` development chain without updating the chain-spec and it will work.

You can specify multiple bootnodes either in the chain spec JSON file or override them on the command line with the `--bootnodes` flag.

For example, here's the Rococo v2_1 chain-spec, which gives many boot nodes.

```
{
  "name": "Rococo",
  "id": "rococo_v2_1",
  "chainType": "Live",
  "bootNodes": [
    "/ip4/34.90.151.124/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWF7BUbG5ErMZ47ZdarRwtpZamgcZqxwpnFzkhjc1spHnP",
    "/ip4/34.90.151.124/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWF7BUbG5ErMZ47ZdarRwtpZamgcZqxwpnFzkhjc1spHnP",
    "/ip4/34.90.137.14/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWLcpkpvjr5ccgtUdTSYtNDjEdsDcPNrt2Rb7yXuAf7bUE",
    "/ip4/34.90.137.14/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWLcpkpvjr5ccgtUdTSYtNDjEdsDcPNrt2Rb7yXuAf7bUE",
    "/ip4/35.204.67.254/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWGjEEDmNbBkXLM1uKMseK9iYD3osKA4JGdGKMZDCusjd6",
    "/ip4/35.204.67.254/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWGjEEDmNbBkXLM1uKMseK9iYD3osKA4JGdGKMZDCusjd6",
    "/ip4/34.90.121.39/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBhkZQydNHDR3XSehnrfj1KNFCdpwgDrYpX54FrUR1FRS",
    "/ip4/34.90.121.39/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWBhkZQydNHDR3XSehnrfj1KNFCdpwgDrYpX54FrUR1FRS",
    "/ip4/34.91.145.35/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBuLAMevZexnFKCgTyoz3AnHQn98D9cfe1Mg3kPoCjkwf",
    "/ip4/34.91.145.35/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWBuLAMevZexnFKCgTyoz3AnHQn98D9cfe1Mg3kPoCjkwf",
    "/ip4/34.91.77.80/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWA5BAM71y9NtV5NH6EjANgYKRZ8jNLJ5z8GJ5RPdjt63n",
    "/ip4/34.91.77.80/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWA5BAM71y9NtV5NH6EjANgYKRZ8jNLJ5z8GJ5RPdjt63n",
    "/ip4/34.91.84.25/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSV4VqhBHZKKBsZKmVU462qRW9PmXTSuYvuajt1P93djA",
    "/ip4/34.91.84.25/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWSV4VqhBHZKKBsZKmVU462qRW9PmXTSuYvuajt1P93djA",
    "/ip4/34.91.97.19/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWD6wC88atMMyVeP6ZKg9sK7QmUL8x8m1RxMW8rhv2vWyg",
    "/ip4/34.91.97.19/tcp/30334/ws/p2p/12D3KooWD6wC88atMMyVeP6ZKg9sK7QmUL8x8m1RxMW8rhv2vWyg"
  ],
  # ... much omitted
}
```

And the help text for `--bootnodes` is:

```
--bootnodes <ADDR>...                                        
            Specify a list of bootnodes
```

Comment: I haven't seen `ws/..` before, does it stand for web socket? If yes why would a node need websocket for peering?

Comment: Yes, it's for websockets. I think that the intention 'ws' addresses are published so nodes running in the browser can connect over websockets. Since they can't use tcp.